# BLE devices background scanning (using android service) can not dicover any BLE device

Tags: java, android, service, android-sqlite, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here is my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
public BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private Button button1,button2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ble_not_supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    if (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();
    }

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScanService.class));
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScanService.class));
        }
    });




}
}
```

Here is my ScanService.class

```
public class ScanService extends Service {

public BluetoothManager mbluetoothManager;
public BluetoothAdapter mbluetoothAdapter;
public final String address1 = "88:4A:EA:76:EA:21";
public final String address2 = "60:64:05:97:5C:05";
public final String address3 = "60:64:05:97:5E:A6";
int i=0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mbluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mbluetoothAdapter = mbluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    mbluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mbluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mbluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        if (device != null && rssi != 127) {
            switch (device.getAddress()) {
                //==============================================================================
                case address1:
                    if (i == 0)
                        Log.d("Beacon:","1");
                    break;
                //==============================================================================
                case address2:
                    if (i == 1) {
                        i = 2;
                        Log.d("Beacon:","2");
                    }
                    break;
                //==============================================================================
                case address3:
                    if (i == 2) {
                        i = 3;
                        Log.d("Beacon:","3");
                    }
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
};

}
```

I can start the scan service but in my log cat it does not return any infomation about the detected beacon, it means that the app is scanning but does not find any beacon. Is there anything else must i put in my service???

Here is my logcat info:
[image]

Comment: Check out https://www.google.com/search?q=ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION+ble